# Running SQL Server stored procedure 'out-of-session'

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, iis-7.5

From a (classic ASP on IIS) web-page a stored procedure is called in SQL Server. The program waits till the stored procedure returns a result but this is not at all necessary. Is there a way to just start the stored procedure and go on?

Mabel

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to put this SP into the job. Then launch job from IIS. Also you can use asynchronous SP launch (you can read [here](http://mobile.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3427581/Submitting-A-Stored-Procedure-Asynchronously.htm) about it).